# Partitioned Collections with < 10k RU/s

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I really would like to use partitioned collection but according and the pricing model $6/month for each 100 RU seems fair. But in the portal the minimum RU/s for partitioned collections are > 10.000 RU/s  which is $600 a month. Is there no way to opt in on partitioned collections with fewer RU reserved?

**EDIT**

Addes this to DocumentDB Uservoice. Please vote.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/13414590-partitioned-collections-with-10k-ru-s

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Azure pricing/service-offering question, not a programming question. The partitioned-collection parameters (as documented [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-partition-data/)), for things like minimum RU, are the boundaries you must work within. I suggest posting your idea to DocumentDB's [uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb).

Comment: Programming question or not, you answered my question. Thanks! Have not seen that document there. But you may consider adding this to the pricing details, a little misleading. (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/documentdb/)

Comment: But David, why is the minimum so high?

Comment: I really can't answer that, as 1) I'm not on the product team, and 2) I'm pretty sure pricing decisions/justifications/discussions (across the entire Azure service suite) are not discussed publicly.

Comment: As I said in the original question I think the pricing is fair. But I´m asking why the minimum Request Units are so hight.

Comment: I agree with David that this is off topic.

Comment: I agree that this is off topic but this is an important discussion. The minimum  RU is too high and misleading from the pricing page.

Comment: Good point. This is a important discussion. Feel free to vote Jonathan.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/13414590-partitioned-collections-with-10k-ru-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to test the programming model e.g. partition key as the transaction boundary, and setting headers like enable cross-partition query, you can do that with single-partition collections (under 10,000 RU/s) and setting a partition key during collection creation. These collections will not scale-out since the throughput can be served from a single partition.

Comment: Right, but you can't set a partition key for one of those through the portal, right?  I tried, and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Yes, this is only supported programmatically. On a related note, the DocumentDB has announced that partitioned collections will support lower entry point on throughput - 2500 RU/s down from 10,000 RU/s.